# fancybox error The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to pop up a fancy box with code below but i am getting the following error.
The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later

```
 $(".sizing-link").on("click", function(event) {   

        $(".sizing-link").fancybox();

    });


  <a href="#" class="sizing-link">What's my size</a>    

    <div style="display: none">
        <div id="inlineContent">
            <h2>Sizing Guide</h2>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 713px;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="129">
        <col span="8" width="73">
    </colgroup>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="xl75" height="27" width="129">Waist - Jeans</td>

            <td class="xl65" width="73">(+/-)</td>

            <td class="xl66" width="73">30</td>

            <td class="xl66" width="73">32</td>

            <td class="xl66" width="73">34</td>

            <td class="xl66" width="73">36</td>

            <td class="xl66" width="73">38</td>

            <td class="xl66" width="73">40</td>

            <td class="xl66" width="73">42</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="xl75" height="24">Waist - Brand's</td>

            <td class="xl68">&nbsp;</td>

            <td class="xl69">30</td>

            <td class="xl70">32</td>

            <td class="xl70">34</td>

            <td class="xl70">36</td>

            <td class="xl70">38</td>

            <td class="xl70">40</td>

            <td class="xl71">42</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="xl75" height="24">Leg Opening</td>

            <td class="xl68">&nbsp;1/8</td>

            <td class="xl74">7 3/4</td>

            <td class="xl70">8</td>

            <td class="xl72">8 1/4</td>

            <td class="xl72">8 3/4</td>

            <td class="xl72">9 1/4</td>

            <td class="xl72">9 1/2</td>

            <td class="xl73">9 3/4</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="xl75" height="24">Hip</td>

            <td class="xl68">&nbsp;1/2</td>

            <td class="xl69">38</td>

            <td class="xl70">40</td>

            <td class="xl70">42</td>

            <td class="xl70">44</td>

            <td class="xl70">46</td>

            <td class="xl70">48</td>

            <td class="xl71">50</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="xl75" height="24">Thigh</td>

            <td class="xl68">&nbsp;1/4</td>

            <td class="xl69">23</td>

            <td class="xl70">24</td>

            <td class="xl70">25</td>

            <td class="xl70">27</td>

            <td class="xl70">28</td>

            <td class="xl70">29</td>

            <td class="xl71">30</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="xl75" height="24">Knee</td>

            <td class="xl76">&nbsp;1/8</td>

            <td class="xl77">8</td>

            <td class="xl78">8 1/4</td>

            <td class="xl78">8 1/2</td>

            <td class="xl79">9</td>

            <td class="xl78">9 1/2</td>

            <td class="xl78">9 3/4</td>

            <td class="xl80">10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
$(".sizing-link").on("click", function(event) {   
     $(".sizing-link").fancybox();
});
```

try this only

```
$(".sizing-link").fancybox();
```

(you don't need the `.on("click")` method)

...**and** instead of this

```
<a href="#" class="sizing-link">What's my size</a>
```

try this

```
<a href="#inlineContent" class="sizing-link">What's my size</a>
```